# Element wise vertical addition in nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a function which takes a nested list as an input. The nested list has a list which again is a nested list. Like -

```
args = [[1,2,3],[5,6,7]], [[3,4,5],[9,11,12]]

or,

args = [[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[15,125,32]], [[3,4,5],[9,11,12],[7,65,1]], [[7,8,12],[15,22,23],[24,1,15]]
```

I have to write a function which adds the elements in the same index of the sublist of the nested list and stores them in a list. The example output will make it clearer -

```
Output for args = [[1,2,3],[5,6,7]], 
                  [[3,4,5],[9,11,12]] would look like -

Output = [[4,6,8],[14,17,19]]

Similarly, for args = [[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[15,125,32]], 
                      [[3,4,5],[9,11,12], [7,65,1]], 
                      [[7,8,12],[15,22,23],[24,1,15]]

Output = [[11,6,20],...so on]
```

Code that I've written -

```
def Variable(*args):
    #res = [[] for i in range(len(args))]
    temp1 = []
    for i in range(0, len(args)):
     #   wow = []
        for j in range(0, len(args[i])):
            add = 0
            for k in range(0, len(args[j])):   

                add += args[k][i][j]

            temp1.append(add) 
    return temp1
```

Right now, for an input -

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
 [[6, 4, 3], [5, 3, 1], [2, 6, 4]],
 [[4, 8, 2], [3, 4, 7], [5, 9, 2]]]
```

I am getting the result as -

```
[11, 14, 8, 12, 12, 14, 14, 23, 15]
```

What I need the result to be -

```
[[11,14,8], [12,12,14], [14,23,15]]
```

I am unable to figure out what changes in logic I should make to get the correct answer. I could write another function to take input from here and then return a list but that is not allowed, I can't use any imports either.

Comment: The variable `wow = []` looks promising, but you forgot to use it.

Comment: I don't get the result of your last example. shouldn't it be  `[[12, 15, 18], ...]`?

Comment: I meant to comment that lol.

Comment: No, I need to add it 'vertically', imagine a vertically stacked numpy array and you're adding the elements of different rows but that belong to the same index in that array.

Comment: then that's not consistent with your first example, it should be `[[4, 6, 8], [14, 17, 19]]`?

Comment: just do  temp1.append([add]) .it should solve your problem

Comment: @njzk2 yes I noticed, I made the change.

Comment: @SnehalRGhungurde no, that doesn't work. It gives me a result like, ```[[11], [14], [8], [12], [12], [14], [14], [23], [15]]``` I already tried it before.

Comment: It should be `wow.append(add)` and then `temp1.append(wow)` on the line below but with 1 less indentation

Comment: then this should be enough: `[[sum(t) for t in zip(*k)] for k in zip(*i)]` (where i is your triple-list input) (https://repl.it/repls/OurNimbleComputation)

Comment: In the function it should be: `[[sum(lst) for lst in zip(*lists)] for lists in zip(*list(*args))]`. @njzk2's version does not work if `*i` is passed as function argument.